# Copy a specific directory from Phar archive in PHP

Tags: php, extract, phar

All is in the header. My application is stored in Phar.
My workflow is really simple.

I work with **PHP 5.6**.

I do some stuff in my application and at a moment, I would like to copy a specific directory stored inside my Phar archive into a specific folder outside the archive.

I read lots of things about [Phar::extractTo](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.extractto.php) method, but it does not work if I select specific directory. For example:

```
$phar->extractTo("/external_path", "folder_inside_phar");
```

shouts me that `folder_inside_phar` is non-existent file in Phar archive. This function has been declared has buggy because it does not understand folder. It only accepts files for the second argument.

*I precise that if I do not mention specific folder, it copies all content of the archive. There is not any problem about Phar access or readonly flag...*

So, is there any workaround for that, or a class developed by someone as open-source content to resolve this issue ?

**Edit**
I change the word "extract" by "copy"

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? Phars are normally used to package code for portability *and use*, not to unpackage it again like a zip archive or something

Comment: I made a web application generator which can provide some static content like bootstrap or jQuery at the end of the process.

Comment: Perhaps you could install with curl from a CDN rather than packaging it. I know this doesn't answer your question by the way :-)

Comment: Yes :) but I provide some static code like welcome page written by myself too.

Comment: You could decouple the JavaScript and host that separately on GitHub then install the same way

Comment: :) If I do not want to bother me I can place all static content into another folder and execute my application through a shell script. But the main interest is that all files are stored in the same archive in order to be able to develop offline. I understand that the GitHub solution is a good workaround but it does not fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed `extractTo` does not work with reading from a Phar directory directly - so, I'd like to share a potential work around here, basically using the Phar Stream Wrapper `phar://` which allows to apply any PHP file function (`file_get_contents`, `scandir`, ...) to Phar archives as well.

Let's assume the Phar builder scripts looks like this (I used `addFromString` to have a simple example):

```
<?php
$phar = new Phar('bundle.phar');
$phar->startBuffering();
$phar->addFromString('a/a1.txt', 'contents of a/a1.txt');
$phar->addFromString('a/a2.txt', 'contents of a/a2.txt');
$phar->addFromString('b/b.txt', 'contents of b/b.txt');
$phar->setStub('<?php __HALT_COMPILER();');
$phar->stopBuffering();
```

Extracting files in directory `a/` now could look like the following:

```
<?php
$targetDirectory = __DIR__ . '/target';
if (!is_dir($targetDirectory)) {
  mkdir($targetDirectory);
}
// read directory using Phar Stream Wrapper
// resolves to `['a1.txt', 'a2.txt']`
$files = scandir('phar://./bundle.phar/a/');
// prefix each file with local path `a/`, e.g. `a1.txt` -> `a/a1.txt`
// resolves to `['a/a1.txt', 'a/a2.txt']`
$files = array_map(function($file) { return 'a/' . $file; }, $files);
// actually extract resolved files to `$targetDirectory`
$phar = new \Phar('./bundle.phar');
$phar->extractTo($targetDirectory, $files);
```

Thus, the main aspect here is that any file function can be used for stream wrappers as well - e.g. the following would work as well:

```
copy('phar://./bundle.phar/b/b.txt', './target/b.txt');
```